# Either / Neither singular or plural

Tags: verb-agreement

I'm new to English. I wonder whether *neither / either* will go with *plural* or *singular* verbs?

Answer (score 3):

Both neither and either are used with singular verbs.

Ex. Neither of you **is** leaving until you have finished your work.

Ex. Either day **is** convenient.

**BE CAREFUL** when you use a **compound subject** with either or neither.
Look at these examples below:

Ex. Neither my father nor my **sisters like** to play soccer.

In this sentence the plural verb **like** agrees with the subject that is closest to it **= sisters=plural**.

Ex. Either a melon or **oranges** **are** on the menu today.

The subject nearest to the verb is **plural=oranges** and so the verb is **plural=are**

Comment: The choice of verb is guided by the pronoun that heads the NP which is the subject. That is the singular pronoun _Either_. The subject is not _oranges_. It is the noun phrase _Either a melon or oranges,_ and that NP is headed by the singular pronoun, which calls for the singular verb. Consider the sentence: _"Neither my family nor I are illiterate."_

Answer (score 1):

According to Oxford Dictionary:

After **neither** and **either** you use a singular verb: *Neither candidate was selected for the job.*

**Neither of** and **either of** are followed by a plural noun or pronoun and a singular or plural verb. A plural verb is more informal: *Neither of my parents speaks/speak a foreign language.*

When **neither… nor…** or **either… or…** are used with two singular nouns, the verb can be singular or plural. A plural verb is more informal.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford Learner's Dictionary provides advice which I think is misleading. It is:

> - **Neither of** and **either of** are followed by a plural noun or pronoun and a singular or plural verb. A plural verb is more informal: *Neither of my parents speaks/​speak a foreign language.*
> - When **neither… nor…** or **either… or…** are used with two singular nouns, the verb can be singular or plural. A plural verb is more informal.

Certainly, there are constructions in which it is difficult to "keep track" of the number of the verb that is called for by the subject. An example is given in the *The American Heritage Book of English Usage*, (Houghton Mifflin, 1996):

> Either John or his brothers *are* bringing the dessert.

Here it may not be immediately clear to some speakers whether the singular "John" or the plural "brothers" should guide them in choosing the number of the verb. It *would* be clear to them if they would but realize that it is neither "John" nor "brothers" that guides the choice of the verb: it is the singular pronoun *Either* that heads the noun phrase which is the subject.

Nevertheless, is true that many English speakers "lose track" of number when using the pairs **neither… nor…** or **either… or…**. The result is something called *proximity agreement.* This is a way to make English more "forgiving", in a way. There is no point in trying to force agreement in number on a population of speakers, and in any case, there is no mechanism with which to force it!

In the *Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English* (2002), Douglas Biber explains it thus:

> ...the **principle of proximity** sometimes plays a part in subject-verb agreement. This principle is the tendency, especially in speech, for the verb to agree with the closest (pro)noun, even when that (pro)noun is not the head of the subject noun phrase. For example:
>
> > *Do you think [any of them] **are** bad Claire? (CONV)
> >
> >         [Not one of the people who's auditioned] **were** up to par. (FICT)*

These examples are obvious, and agreement in number in any case is not as important as being understood by listeners or readers.

However, *Oxford Learners* gives bad advice to learners when they tell them that it is acceptable to say:

> *Neither of my parents ​speak a foreign language.*

If we remove the preposition phrase, it is easy to see that the singular is called for:

> *Neither ​speaks a foreign language.*

In this case, they are giving bad, or at least incomplete advice to learners. The last sentence of the entry should be:

> **It is *never* wrong to use a singular verb form with *either* or *neither.***

Comment: So using singular always correct?

Comment: But what about if we have **or** / **nor** word?

Comment: @Viettungvuong Even when you use _neither ... nor_ or _either ... or_, you will be on firm ground if you use the singular verb.

Comment: In this sentence: Neither the boy nor the girls ____, singular and plural are both correct?

Comment: @Viettungvuong In the clause _"Neither the boy nor the girls"_, neither is singular. It is **always** singular. _"Neither the boy nor the girls **is** hungry."_ Some speakers may use the plural here, but you will **always be correct** to use the singular.

Comment: Do you mean that *Neither you nor I is* ... is correct, while *are* is wrong? If this is what you mean, then only twenty-five percent of English speakers get this correct. ([See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Neither+you+nor+I+is+%2C+Neither+you+nor+I+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNeither%20you%20nor%20I%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNeither%20you%20nor%20I%20are%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CNeither%20you%20nor%20I%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNeither%20you%20nor%20I%20are%3B%2Cc0))? Do you have any reference confirming this?

Comment: *"Neither the boys nor the girls"* ***really*** needs a plural verb.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a formal setting you should use a singular verb. If you are in an informal setting, it's OK to use a plural verb.

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either):

> In formal styles, we use neither of with a singular verb when it is
>   the subject. However, in informal speaking, people often use plural
>   verbs:
>
> Neither of my best friends was around.
>
> Neither of them were interested in going to university.

---

In informal settings, I often hear people say something like the following:

> I tried the red cake and the blue cake. Neither were very good.

Thus, I don't think [the principle of proximity](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/136072/85852) has much to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

The [AP Stylebook](https://www.apstylebook.com/) disagrees with the other answers and says:

> **either...or, neither...nor**
>
> The nouns that follow these words do not constitute a compound
>   subject; they are alternate subjects and require a verb that agrees
>   with the nearer subject: Neither they nor he is going. Neither he nor
>   they are going.